# Problema al realizar operaciones con lista .Net

Tags: c#, .net

tengo un inconveniente, resulta que estoy haciendo un registro de ventas, muy básico, todo va bien al momento de mostrar los datos ingresados en un ListView, el problema esta en que al final de ingresar todas las ventas, tengo que mostrar cual fue el producto mas vendido, los productos se comprenden en 3, que seria DC-8, DC-9, DC-10, al momento de agregar los datos al ListView, también estos se me guardan en una lista respectivamente, pero poseo una función aparte, que debería cumplir con el objetivo de poder realizar la operación de encontrar el producto mas vendido, podría decir que me almacena los valores en la lista, pero esto no se me operan como tal, si no que los valores de cantidad se me suman, en ves de filtrarse y mostrar el mayor.

Como lo mostrare en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo podrán notar, me dice que el modelo DC-10 si es el mas vendido, pero al momento de mostrar se me suma la cantidad que antes se agregó a otros modelos, aunque tengo una observación, sin importar que el DC-8 para poner de ejemplo sea el que tiene mayor cantidad, este me mostrara que el DC-10 es el que mas se ha vendido.

Adjunto código a continuación:

**Clase Organizador**, esta clase es donde creo los parámetros que se me almacenaran en las listas.

```
public class Organizador
    {
        string cCompania;
        int cCreacion;
        int cVenta;
        int cantidad;

        public Organizador()
        {
            cCompania = string.Empty;
            cCreacion = 0;
            cVenta = 0;
            cantidad = 0;
            
        }
        public Organizador(string compania,int creacion, int venta,int cantidad)
        {
            this.cCreacion = creacion;
            this.cCompania = compania;
            this.cVenta = venta;
            this.cantidad = cantidad;
        }
        public string CCompania
        {
            get => cCompania;
            set => cCompania = value;
        }
        public int CCreacion
        {
            get => cCreacion;
            set => cCreacion = value;
        }
        public int CVenta
        {
            get => cVenta;
            set => cVenta = value; 
        }
        public int Cantidad
        {
            get => cantidad;
            set => cantidad = value;
        }
    }
```

**Clase del Form**, código donde se encuentra todo la ejecución del Form.

```
public partial class FrmRegistro : Form
    {
        int CCreacionDC8 = 1000,CVentaDC8=1500,CVentaDC9=3500,CVentaDC10=6000, CCreacionDC9 = 2500, CCreacionDC10 = 5000;

        List<Organizador> DC_8;
        List<Organizador> DC_9;
        List<Organizador> DC_10;
        public FrmRegistro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DC_8 = new List<Organizador>();
            DC_9 = new List<Organizador>();
            DC_10 = new List<Organizador>();
        }
        public List<Organizador> Lista_DC_8
        {
            get => DC_8;
            set => DC_8 = value;
        }
        public  List<Organizador> Lista_DC_9
        {
            get => DC_9;
            set => DC_9 = value;
        }
        public  List<Organizador> Lista_DC_10
        {
            get => DC_10;
            set => DC_10 = value;
        }

        private void FrmRegistro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblFecha.Text = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("d");
            LblCC.Text = (0).ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
            LblCV.Text = (0).ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
            LblTotal.Text= (0).ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
        }

        private void CmbModelo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string producto = CmbModelo.Text;

            if (producto.Equals("DC-8"))
            {
                LblCC.Text = CCreacionDC8.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
                LblCV.Text = CVentaDC8.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
            }
            else if (producto.Equals("DC-9"))
            {
                LblCC.Text = CCreacionDC9.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
                LblCV.Text = CVentaDC9.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
            }
            else if (producto.Equals("DC-10"))
            {
                LblCC.Text = CCreacionDC10.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
                LblCV.Text = CVentaDC10.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
            }

        }

        private void BtnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BtnMMVendido_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mMVedido();
        }

        private void BtnRegresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmAcceso frmAcceso = new FrmAcceso();
            this.Hide();
            frmAcceso.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void BtnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Validacion
            if (CmbModelo.SelectedIndex==-1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un modelo!");
            }
            else if(txtCompania.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe de Ingresar el nombre de la Compañia!");
            }
            else if(txtCantidad.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Seleccione una cantidad!");
            }
            else
            {
                string producto = CmbModelo.Text;
                int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text);
                string com = txtCompania.Text;

                float total=0.0f;
                if(producto.Equals("DC-8"))
                {
                    total = cantidad * CVentaDC8;
                }
                else if(producto.Equals("DC-9"))
                {
                    total = cantidad * CVentaDC9;
                }
                else if(producto.Equals("DC-10"))
                {
                    total = cantidad * CVentaDC10;
                }
                //Imprimiendo los resultados
                ListViewItem fila = new ListViewItem(producto);
                fila.SubItems.Add(com.ToString());
                fila.SubItems.Add(cantidad.ToString());
                if (producto.Equals("DC-8"))
                {
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CCreacionDC8.ToString());
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CVentaDC8.ToString());
                }
                else if (producto.Equals("DC-9"))
                {
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CCreacionDC9.ToString());
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CVentaDC9.ToString());
                }
                else if (producto.Equals("DC-10"))
                {
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CCreacionDC10.ToString());
                    fila.SubItems.Add(CVentaDC10.ToString());
                }
                fila.SubItems.Add(total.ToString());
                LvRVenta.Items.Add(fila);

                BtnCancelar_Click(sender, e);
            }

            Organizador registroDC_8 = new Organizador(txtCompania.Text, CCreacionDC8, CVentaDC8, Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text));
            DC_8.Add(registroDC_8);
            Organizador registroDC_9 = new Organizador(txtCompania.Text, CCreacionDC9, CVentaDC9, Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text));
            DC_9.Add(registroDC_9);
            Organizador registroDC_10 = new Organizador(txtCompania.Text, CCreacionDC10, CVentaDC10, Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text));
            DC_10.Add(registroDC_10);

        }
        public void mMVedido() //Función en donde se supone que hago el filtrado de los datos
        {
            int cantidad1 = 0, cantidad2 = 0, cantidad3 = 0;
            foreach (Organizador item in Lista_DC_8)
            {
                cantidad1 += item.Cantidad;
            }

            foreach (Organizador item in Lista_DC_9)
            {
                cantidad2 += item.Cantidad;

            }
            foreach (Organizador item in Lista_DC_10)
            {
                cantidad3 += item.Cantidad;

            }

            if (cantidad1 > cantidad2 && cantidad1 > cantidad3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El modelo mas vendido es el DC-8 con: " + cantidad1);
            }
            else if (cantidad2 > cantidad1 && cantidad2 > cantidad3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El modelo mas vendido es el DC-9 con: " + cantidad2);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El modelo mas vendido es el DC-10 con: " + cantidad3);
            }
        }


    }
```

Cualquier consejo o ayuda es será bien recibida.

Comment: Hay demasiado codigo para analizar.. pero los primeros problemas que veo es que tenes 3 listas cuando deberias tener una sola. Explicame porque hay 3 listas?

Comment: Por qué solo son 3 productos, necesito almanecar el modelo, su costo de producción, su costo de venta y su cantidad, si esto yo lo guardo en una sola lista, después a mí se me hace complicado desarrollarme, es por eso que decidí crear 3 listas.

Comment: Y eso es todo lo que te esta generando mil problemas.. porque hay 3 listas? cuando deberia ser una lista de productos con 3 productos distintos? cual es el problema de tener una sola lista? por ahi, empiezan tus problemas (los mil if por todos lados, el mismo codigo repetido.. si fueran 10 productos que hacemos?)

Comment: Otras cosas.. hay getters y setter totalmente innecesarios dentro de tu form. hay codigo que parece innesario en el constructor del form.. esto -> FrmAcceso frmAcceso = new FrmAcceso();
            this.Hide();
            frmAcceso.ShowDialog(); en el boton volver, no vuelve al formulario que te trajo, genera uno nuevo.. eso puede que este ok.. pero oculta este, no lo cierra....

Comment: tal vez, te iria mejor preguntando en el [chat]

Comment: Está bien, gracias, eliminaré la pregunta.

Comment: No es necesario que elimines la pregunta... pero estas preguntando algo mas complejo que lo que pensas, porque tenes otros problemas de base.. tal vez debas preguntar por esos primero?

Comment: Realmente no se cómo preguntar concretamente, en la universidad no me enseñan técnicamente nada, solo me envían los trabajos y tengo que ser autodidacta, tal vez me esté saltando conceptos de gran importancia, pero es complicado profundizar cada tema, veré la posibilidad de almanecar todo en una sola lista y organizar mejor el código, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Por eso te digo.. en el [chat] se te puede ayudar mejor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al revisar el código veo que tienes varios inconvenientes (demasiado código redundante, entre otros aspectos...) por haber guardado tus datos en tres listas diferentes, deberías de guardar tus datos en una misma lista, pero si por alguna *"razón de orden superior"* no puedes, te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente.

Primero a tu clase Organizador agrégale una propiedad Llama Modelo, luego te recomiendo que unifiques las tres listas en una sola y con Linq generes una consulta donde agrupes tus datos por nombre, luego generas un nuevo objeto donde guardes el nombre del avión y su cantidad, luego los ordenes y selecciones el primero de esta manera obtendrás el avión mas vendido:

```
        var lista = new List<Organizador>();
        lista.AddRange(DC_8);
        lista.AddRange(DC_9);
        lista.AddRange(DC_10);

        lista.GroupBy(x => x.Modelo, (key, v) => new
        {
            Modelo = key,
            Cantidad = v.Count()
        }).OrderBy(v=>v.Cantidad).FirstOrDefault();
```

Para que agregar la propiedad Modelo en la clase Organizador, para poder tener el modelo que vendes en la clase organizador y no en la Lista que no es lo recomendado... De igual forma este código es para dar una solución rápida a lo que quieres, pero si tienes tiempo mejora toda tu lógica.

Comment: Es un ejercicio de la facultad (lee los comentarios) es dudoso que OP sepa siquiera lo que hace linq, cuando uso 3 listas porque tiene problemas para usar una sola que contenga 3 objetos....

Comment: A lo que voy, si le das una solucion con linq, que sea completa, con la explicacion de que hace cada parte de linq, y las referencias a la documentacion....

Comment: Que procede ???

Comment: Logre darle una solución, simplemente agregando los datos a la lista cuando hago la condicional de Equals, de cada if, de este modo cuando se me iguala la opción del combobox, se me agreguen todos los dato a la lista, una vez guardado, simplemente opere como lo hice al final del código, es menos practico, pero me ha funcionado.